# Go to particular div without scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need to land a particular element on click but without scrolling. Below I have a code but it is scrolling to a particular element on click, Is there any way to go to a particular HTML element without scroll?

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("html, body).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myelement").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Change animate time from `2000` to `0`.

Comment: decrease duration.

Comment: Use `<a>` tag with attribute `href="#myelement"` if that help, I don't think you need Javascript for this.

Comment: `window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/\#(.*?)+/,"#myelement")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="#test" id="GoToAtag">Go to p tag</a>
<div style="background-color:lightblue;height:800px" >

</div>

<p id="test">This is some text.</p>
<a href="#GoToAtag">Go to a tag</a>
```

Check this one for move to any element using ID and anchor 
or try this 
jsfiddle.net/thepeanut/ohhffte6 url

Comment: I need to do in jquery or javascript

Comment: it will work without javascript and jquery i did not understand why you need in JS

Comment: I have third party library thats why what you have written i already know dude

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/thepeanut/ohhffte6/ 
 try this one i think it may help you

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine. Now, it is going on top instantly without animation. When i am firing click event..

```
$("#button").click(function() {
     $("html, body").scrollTop(0);
});
```